# Issues with Unicode to UTF-8 Conversion in C using iconv Library

Tags: c, iconv

I am attempting to convert a Unicode character represented as "\u5317" to its corresponding UTF-8 character in C using the iconv library. In Ruby, the conversion is achieved using the following code:

```rb
["5317"].pack("H*").unpack("n*").pack("U*")
```

This successfully outputs the UTF-8 character "北". However, when trying to accomplish the same task in C using the iconv library, the output is not as expected. Here is the C code snippet I am using:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iconv.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main() {
    iconv_t cd = iconv_open("UTF-8", "ASCII");
    char* inbuf = "5317";
    size_t inbytesleft = strlen(inbuf);
    char dest_str[100];
    char* outbuf = dest_str;
    size_t outbytesleft = sizeof dest_str;

    if (iconv(cd, &inbuf, &inbytesleft, &outbuf, &outbytesleft) != (size_t)(-1)) {
        printf("success: %s\n", outbuf);
    } else {
        printf("failed\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this C code is "success:", but it does not display the expected UTF-8 character. I suspect there might be an issue with my usage of the iconv library or the choice of encoding. Can anyone guide me on the correct way to achieve this conversion in C using iconv or suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: Try setting locale. You want to convert unicode character \u5317 or _the string_ "5317" to unicode and then to utf-8? `pack("H*")` would be `strtol(... 16)`

Comment: The string `"5317"` has the same representation in ASCII and UTf-8. If you want the UTF-8 representation of a particular codepoint, just use `const char *s = u8"\u5317";`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I want to convert the \u5317 to utf-8

Comment: Just `char* inbuf = "\u5317"; printf("%s\n", inbuf);` will "work" and the conversion is already done by the compiler at compilation. ASCII is not able to "represent" UTF-8 , isn't iconv_open("UTF-8", "ASCII") a no-op? You can just do `char *inbuf = "北"` and save your file with your editor in UTF-8 for that matter.

Comment: @KamilCuk Appreciate your clarification! It seems like I misunderstood the usage of iconv for this specific task